# How to transform a series object into a single string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, google-sheets-api

I have a series of id's that I need to input into google sheet via API.

The problem:

- The just accept a single string for cell as input NOT series or list
- Need to merge this series into a string dividing by comma

Series

```
0   0000021
1   0000021
2   0000021
3   00df5461651
4   0000021
5   0077777777

Name: id, dtype: object
```

Desired output

```
string = "0000021, 0000021, 0000021, 00df5461651, 0000021, 0077777777"
```

Code

```
g_plat= cw.loc[cw.platform =="Google"]

g_plat = g_plat.id


insertRow = [ "Google", f"{year}/{month}/{day}" ,f"Google = {g_plat}
sheet.insert_row(insertRow, 2)


TypeError: Object of type Series is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: what about `','.join(s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work?

```
ww = pd.Series(['0000021', '0000021', '0000021'])
ww = ww.to_list()
', '.join(ww)
```

Comment: It works @svenhalvorson , only problem is cell do not accepted the string I got API error, but I inserted it as a row..
so not perfect but works!! thank you